# F# selecting a single value in an array

Tags: f#

I am diving into F# for the first time, trying to follow Luca's example found [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/pdc2008/tl11).
I am doing pretty well parsing an input file, but I am stuck in trying to filter my sequence based on the value of 1 value in an array.  Here is the

```
    let fileStream = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read)
    let streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream)
    let contents = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
    let cleanContents =
        contents.Split([|'\n'|])
        |> Seq.map(fun line -> line.Split([|'\t'|]))
        |> Seq.filter(fun values -> values |> Seq.length = 6)
```

When I try and add this,

```
|> Seq.filter(fun values -> values |> values[0].length = 8)
```

I get an a compile error.  What I want to do is to check that the 1st column in the sequence has 8 characters only, no more or less.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just get rid of `values |>`.

Comment: I did this to get it to work:|> Seq.filter(fun values -> values.[0].Length = 8)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is forward piping "values". This makes no sense.

```
|> Seq.filter(fun values -> values[0].length = 8)
```

should work.

(UPDATE: I missed the comments to the question and this is just to not that ildjarn answered this first in a comment)